# Can we use "gift" for non-material thing, e.g. "My dad took me to the amusement park as a gift"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[Dictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/gift_1?q=gift) say "*a gift: a thing that you give to somebody, especially on a special occasion or to say thank you*"

I am not sure if "**a thing**" here can be a non-material thing.

For example, "*That day was my birthday and my dad took me to the amusement park as a gift*"?

If we can not use "**a gift**", what other word can we use?

**Note**: I thought about "*My dad took me to the amusement park as a reward*"

However, that was my birthday and I expected to get a gift not a reward because a reward is used for something I did well like a good mark for example.

Comment: Have you ever heard of the phrase "the gift of knowledge"?

Comment: ''As a treat'', ''as a birthday present'' or ''he treated me to X''.  ''Gift'' sounds a bit odd as it makes it sound like the trip was a material object which could be given by hand.

Comment: @DKNguyen and even more popular (based on February saturation): gift of love?

Comment: To sum up the answers: money and your time are *giveable*, too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, **as a gift** is idiomatic there. Compare:

> They took us to the movies *as a treat*.
>
> She put her hand on her forehead *as a clue*.
>
> He ate some peanuts *as a snack*.
>
> He washed their car as a gift.

The phrases beginning with **as** refer to the *purpose or intention* of the action spoken about.  Another preposition you could use in such contexts is **for**:  for a treat, for a clue, for a snack, for a gift.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the peanut example. (I'm a native speaker, Maritimes.) Peanuts are a physical thing and a snack can be a physical thing (what you eat during a snack [meal]), so I'd break it down as "He ate a snack. The snack was peanuts."

Comment: Secondly, "for a snack" is good but the other ones with "for" sound weird to me. I'd interpret "for" more like "in order to get", like, say, "She put her hand on her forehead [to signal that she wanted] a clue", "He washed their car [hoping they would give him] a gift", and, a little more loosely, "They took us to the movies [the movie theater] [in order to get] a treat" (like popcorn).

Comment: @wjandrea:  **snack** can be understood as a purpose.   *He ate some peanuts as a pick-me-up*. It's how you understand **snack**.

Comment: @wjandrea  Your use of **for** is indeed one of its meanings; but prepositions are polysemous, and the examples I've given, where the meaning is one of function or purpose, are idiomatic.  *They tossed the struggling swimmer an inner-tube for life-preserver.*

Comment: The physicality  of the thing is a red-herring grammar-wise, but semantically it would have bearing. *She uttered a curse as a snack* wouldn't work because there's no way to understand cursing as snacking, but **The wrestler was only six ounces away from the required weight, so he imagined a piece of cake for a snack** would work.

Comment: That example, *"They tossed the struggling swimmer an inner-tube for life-preserver"*, sounds very literary to me, or maybe in a dialect I'm not familiar with. Could you cite a real-world example?

Comment: **We couldn't get a magician so we hired a clown as|for a stand-in.**  I will look for some others.

Comment: "for a stand-in" also sounds weird to me

Comment: "Sleep for dinner" might be a real-world example of what you're saying, I'm not sure. Although "dinner" is being used figuratively.

Comment: How about, *She didn't have anything with her to carry the ducklings in, so she used her apron for a basket*.

Comment: What's that from? It also sounds literary to me.

Comment: **He was owed more than $100,000 which he planned to use for a down-payment on a house.**

Comment: **I couldn't reach it up on that top shelf and there was nothing to use for a step-stool.**

Comment: **The bear was coming at me and there was nothing to use for a weapon.**

Comment: The down-payment example isn't as good as the step-stool and weapon examples, because it is more like **Here are some apples to use for a pie.** where you couldn't swap **for** with **as**,.

Comment: So there are shades of meaning within purpose or intention:  standing in place of, in lieu of (**as**, **for**) and "in contribution to" (**for** but not **as**)

Answer (score 15):

Absolutely! There is nothing that stops somebody from describing an experience (like taking you to an Amusement Park) as a "gift" in English.

Comment: Yes, exactly. As a native speaker seeing the title of the question, my first thoughts were "of course!" "absolutely". I have heard it used this way (non material) enough that I had never though of there being a distinction, and would actually find it a little odd if someone insisted on that distinction between material and non-material. Many times, the **best gifts  are the non-material ones!**

Comment: But, as @Hollis Williams says, _as a treat_ would be more idiomatic, at least in British English.

Comment: But as a Native English speaker, it's fine.

Answer (score 5):

It's quite true that *usually*, gifts are *physical things **given.*** Note that ***gift*** and ***give*** are cognate (they have the same origin, so they're effectively the noun and verb versions of "the same" word). There's nothing syntactically incorrect about *Dad gave me a trip to Disney World*, though. (Except some people might assume he gave me ***a ticket***, rather than actually took me there! :)

But I'd want to know what exactly is the *reason*<sup>1</sup> for including ***as a gift*** in the sentence? Presumably it's not to clarify that Dad didn't ask me to *pay* for the trip. Consider also...

> 1: *My dad let me stay up late to watch the game on TV **as a gift***

...which I suggest is even *more* "awkward" than OP's example. Reason being that in nearly all cases where I might wish to attach some kind of *reason* to such a "parental boon", that reason would effectively amount to a ***reward*** (for having done my homework, tidied my room, etc.), so...

> 2: *My dad took me to the amusement park **as a reward***

...is fine if the context makes it clear what I did to merit being rewarded. Alternatively, if there's no obvious "activity / achievement + reward" combination in play,...

> 3: *My dad took me to the amusement park **as a favour***

You can find more alternatives by googling **synonym reward favour gift.** One that might sometimes be more suitable, depending on the *exact* context, is...

> **indulgence** [<sup>Cambridge Dictionary</sup>](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/indulgence)
> *an occasion when you allow someone or yourself to have something  enjoyable, especially **more than is good for you***

...where it might be that the highlighted element above amounts to *more than is good **for the family finances*** (i.e. the family can't easily afford the trip, but the child is going to be indulged anyway).

---

<sup>1</sup> Noting the now-revised question text, it now seems pretty obvious OP's context would be best served by...

> 4: *My dad took me to the amusement park as a **[birthday] present***

...where I suggest the "optional" element should normally be included unless preceding context has clearly established that the *reason* for the trip is *it's a **birthday** present*.

Comment: Now, that was my birthday and I expected to get a gift not a reward because a reward is used for something I did well like a good mark for example.

Comment: You really should have included that in your original question. I could have written a much shorter answer - but I'm not going to delete all the irrelevant aspects now, as they might be useful to others in future.

Comment: *"That day was my birthday and my dad took me to the amusement park[.]"* A querent might not even use the word either. *What did your dad get (gift) you for your BD?* - *"He took me to an AP."* - Everything costs money. This is implied. This is known. This is being a dad. See also, the intro to, *Married With Children*.

Comment: @Mazura: I kinda doubt any native Anglophone has said *What did your dad **gift** you for your birthday?* for at least a century! In fact, it's probably *never* been said before, because ***dad*** there is informal, but ***gift*** as a verb is poetic / dated / formal.

Answer (score 4):

A way to approach words that are ambiguous like this is to try them with different verbs and you will often find that there is a pattern to the usage. With your question, specifically, you're on the right track in that you know what the rule FEELS like, but just not how to explain it. A *'gift'* can absolutely be non-material things (especially if you're my parents around my birthday) but it's the wording of the sentence that makes it feel wrong. A pattern you will see with words like *'gift'* is that they tend to always have a **"to be"** verb with them (think *'I am', 'we were', 'she was'*, etc.). A way to reword your example sentence that would help it sound more colloquial would be *"My dad's gift to me **was** a trip to the amusement park".*

Great question. Hope that helps!